# Pass Int Values to GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, formik

I am running a graphql query with these data types:

```
mutation AddVehicle(
    $freeSeats: Number!
    $numberPlate: String!
    $userId: Number!
  )
```

On my front-end, I am using material ui text-fields, which take an input as a string by default. To change it into integers, I used `Number(freeSeats)`etc while passing parameters into the `submitForm`function.

However, when I submit the form I still get these errors, which means that the values are still being passed as strings. How can I fix this?

```
 The specified value type of field `freeSeats` does not match the field type.
GraphQL error: The specified value type of field `userId` does not match the field type.
```

I also tried to `console.log(isNumber(freeSeats)` in the beginning of the `submitForm` function. It prints true. So I know that the strings are being converted to integers but not being passed correctly in the mutation.

```
export default function AddVehiclePage() {
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const [addVehicle] = useMutation(ADD_VEHICLE);

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues:{
            freeSeats: '',
            numberPlate: '',
            userId: '',
        },
        onSubmit:(values, actions) => {
          submitForm(Number(formik.values.freeSeats),formik.values.numberPlate,Number(formik.values.userId));           
           validationSchema:schema
        })

    let submitForm = (
        freeSeats: Number,
        numberPlate: string,
        userId: Number,
    ) => {
      setIsSubmitted(true);
      addVehicle({
        variables: {
          freeSeats: freeSeats,
          numberPlate: numberPlate,
          userId: userId,
        },
      })
        .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<CreateVehicleResponse>) => {
          if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
            setIsAdded(true);
          }
        })
        .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
          console.log('Error msg:' + error.message);
        });
    };

    return (
      <div>
                <Form
                  onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    formik.handleSubmit();
                  }}>
                  <div>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      margin="normal"
                      id="freeSeats"
                      name="freeSeats"
                      helperText={formik.touched.freeSeats ? formik.errors.freeSeats : ''}
                      error={formik.touched.freeSeats && Boolean(formik.errors.freeSeats)}
                      label="Free Seats"
                      value={formik.values.freeSeats}
                      onChange={props => {
                        formik.handleChange(props);
                        formik.handleBlur(props);
                      }}
                      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    />
                    <br></br>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      margin="normal"
                      id="numberPlate"
                      name="numberPlate"
                      helperText={formik.touched.numberPlate ? formik.errors.numberPlate : ''}
                      error={formik.touched.numberPlate && Boolean(formik.errors.numberPlate)}
                      label="Number Plate"
                      value={formik.values.numberPlate}
                      onChange={props => {
                        formik.handleChange(props);
                        formik.handleBlur(props);
                      }}
                      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    />
                    <br></br>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      margin="normal"
                      id="userId"
                      name="userId"
                      helperText={formik.touched.userId ? formik.errors.userId: ''}
                      error={formik.touched.userId && Boolean(formik.errors.userId)}
                      label="User Id"
                      value={formik.values.userId}
                      onChange={props => {
                        formik.handleChange(props);
                        formik.handleBlur(props);
                      }}
                      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    />
                    <br></br>
                    <CustomButton                    
                      text={'Add'}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: prepare working [example]

Comment: I made a sandbox. The userId is mentioned at the end @xadm https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-browser-qjof4?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import { Int } from "type-graphql";`

Changing the type from Number to Int within the mutation worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt(freeSeats)` to convert a string to a number.

Please bear in mind:

- In some cases for example if the number in the string is preceded by a 0, this may give you an incorrect value as there are various rules to determine whether the number in the string is binary, hexadecimal (base 6) or octal (base 8) instead of our standard base 10 counting system. If this happens you’ll need to add a second parameter to the method telling it the number is in base 10: `parseInt(freeSeats, 10)`
- If the string is incorrectly formed or empty, you could still end up with the values NaN or undefined. You may want to put checks in against these values before trying to use them.

Comment: parseInt() didn't work either in this case. I tried using it where I am calling the submitForm function.

Comment: @Jnl I’m not familiar with Formik, but if parseInt doesn’t work then I’d suspect you’re getting through values that aren’t numbers (resulting in NaN or undefined) and that’s causing it to fail. Looking at the code it does seem like you may be getting an array here instead of a single value. Try adding a console log in your function to find out what the value is before calling submitForm. That should help figure it out!

Comment: I have already tried that. Maybe you could have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-browser-qjof4?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Number` type in graphql (check docs) ... probably should be `Int` or even `ID!`

Defining type `Number` can be not enough in typescript ... https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/11/05/using-an-int-type-in-typescript/

If Int is enough (for graphQL) then at least do conversion here:

```
addVehicle({
    variables: {
      freeSeats: parseInt(freeSeats),
```

Comment: Doing this will give me ```Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)```Probabaly because I am initialising them as empty strings first. Null didn't work so how could I change that?

Comment: If I change ```freeSeats: Number```to ```Id```or ```int``` there's no such type ```Cannot find name 'Int'.ts(2304)```

Comment: show graphql types, try simpe `parseInt()`, api/mutation tested in playground, compare raw request in browser dev tools/network